# Remote file is not getting accessed if path comes from web.config

Tags: c#

In web.config,

```
 <add key="Uploads"  value="\\\\192.19.165.115\\image_dir\\"/>
```

C# code:

```
 uploadsPath = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Uploads"].ToString());
```

Its returning file with below statement

```
return File("\\\\192.19.165.115\\image_dir\\" + name, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, name);
```

But, it is throwing below error with this line of code.

```
return File(uploadsPath + name, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, name);
```

Error:

```
[COMException (0x80070006): The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
[HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070006.]
```

Both are same paths. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you look at CertificateSignaturePath + name in debug mode? And tell us the purpose of uploadsPath here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Web config the value should be this:

```
 <add key="Uploads"  value="\\192.19.165.115\image_dir\"/>
```